# Why do personnel in the KSC launch control room face away from the launchpad?

Tags: launch-site, kennedy-space-center, facility

The [firing rooms](http://apollolaunchcontrol.com/firing-rooms/) of the Kennedy Space Center have enormous windows that face the launch pads.

[image: KSC Launch Control Center]

However, personnel faced away from the windows, and thus away from the launchpad.  **Is there a documented reason why?**

[image: Apollo layout of firing room]
[image: LCC cross-section]

Comment: speculation: to reduce distraction.

Comment: @Hobbes: That would have been my guess.  Although the weather-person would be the one position I would want looking out a window, rather than at a screen.  ;^)

Answer (score 4):

For shuttle, they didn't. At least not all of the consoles. Note the wood-covered consoles in the rear, they face the window.

This is Firing Room 4 which controlled the last 20 or so shuttle launches.

[image]

[Source](https://petecrownasa.wordpress.com/category/launch-control-firing-rooms/)

A view from one of the consoles in Firing Room 3 which also faced the windows.

[image]

(Personal photo)

Answer (score 2):

This let personnel observe the display screens shown at top in the cutaway diagram.  Those displays mattered more than anything they could see through the windows.

Comment: What do you mean by "injury"?  Blindness?  Shrapnel?

Comment: Oh I deleted my comment quickly because I simply missed the link that was there already. Never mind.

Comment: At liftoff their job was done, it was OK to turn around and look then.

Comment: In that diagram, only about 1/3 of the room can see those upper display screens from their seat, so that doesn't explain the orientation of most people in the room.

Comment: @NuclearWang those screens had been removed by the late shuttle era. See 1st picture in my answer, they just had posters up there.

Comment: In that photo, below the posters, what is the "universal time" clock?  UTC ddd:hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune that's correct.

Comment: I hope your spinal cord within the vertebral column is well protected against injuries, but it is a bit fragile.

Comment: Wayne Hale says "Those big louvers on the windows facing the launch pad were merely for shade, not for blast protection.  If something big hit them, they would probably just add to the shrapnel."  https://waynehale.wordpress.com/2019/08/27/660/  Moonport is ambiguous saying both  "Two-centimeter-thick glass windows with adjustable sun
visors in special aluminum frames faced the launch area" and "could be closed quickly in an emergency" https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19790003956

Comment: That settles it.  You don't make blast door frames out of aluminum.  I retract my claim about shrapnel protection.